# Getting 'Type error' when using navigator share on iOS 14 and below

Tags: angular, share, navigator

I want to share an image on Instagram or other social media with a button click. With the help of navigator share, so far my code worked in Android and iOS 16, but with iOS 14 or below it keeps returning TypeError without anything else specific and not allow me to share.
Currently I'm using Angular 12.

My code to get share data:

```
private async getShareData() {
    if (!this._blob) {
      this._blob = await (await fetch(this._shareImgSrc)).blob();
    }
    const file = new File([this._blob], 'image.png', { type: this._blob.type });

    return {
      files: [file],
    };
  }
```

My code to share when click:

```
public async onShare() {
    if (this._isLoading) {
      return;
    }

    this._isLoading = true;
    try {
      const data = await this.getShareData() as ShareData;
      await navigator.share(data)
    } catch (error) {
      alert(`error: ${error.message}`);
    }
    this._isLoading = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Navigator Share is not support on ios 14